# getting an error Unknown command: 'celery' with celery and supervisor

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

i am trying to setup celery with supervisord on AWS instance. I have the project up running on a virtual environment and i tested the celery by "python2.7 manage.py celery worker". But i am getting an error Unknown command: 'celery' while running with supervisor.

My supervisor configuration are below

1)

```
[program:celery-eatio]
environment = PYTHONPATH="/home/ubuntu/eatio_env/lib/python2.7:/home/ubuntu/eatio-server:/home/ubuntu/eatio_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH",DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="eatio_web.settings"
command=/home/ubuntu/eatio-server/manage.py celery worker 
user=ubuntu
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/celery_error.log
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/celery_out.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

2)

```
[program:celery-eatio]
command=/home/ubuntu/eatio_env/bin/python2.7 /home/ubuntu/eatio-server/manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info -c 1 -E -B -Q celery_periodic -n periodic_worker
directory=/home/ubuntu/eatio-server
user=ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/celery_error.log
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/celery_out.log
```

Comment: you are running the celery worker using the django `manage.py` command? This is no longer required. Your second stanza is missing the `environment` setting.  Can you show the exact supervisord command and error message?

Comment: i am getting Unknown command: 'celery' on the log

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the log line. And please explain if your second stanza is deliberately omitting the `environment` setting.